# Iterating over a Nested List and Changing Values

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists

I have tried to find this answer, but can only find it in pieces which I'm having trouble putting together.

Assume I have:

`aList = [["Monday", "2.03","4.03"],["Tuesday","4.03","5.03"],["Wednesday","3.2","4.3"]]`

I would like to iterate over this nested list and change the numbered string values to floats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aList = [["Monday", "2.03","4.03"],
         ["Tuesday","4.03","5.03"],
         ["Wednesday","3.2","4.3"]]

def helper(s):
    try: return float(s)
    except ValueError: return s

aList[:] = [[helper(item) for item in subl] for subl in aList]
print aList
```

out:

```
[['Monday', 2.03, 4.03], ['Tuesday', 4.03, 5.03], ['Wednesday', 3.2, 4.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in aList:
    item[1] = float(item[1])
    item[2] = float(item[2])
```

Comment: This ans is simpler and more pythonic. Of course if we sure in data